# Facebook Page admin access problem

Tags: facebook

I made a Facebook page from my account and added a friend as its admin with me. But later on we had some conflicts and I removed him from admin but now I don't know how he removed me from admin and gained full control of page.

Can I get my control back?

Comment: Your best bet might be contact Facebook with evidence that you really were the creator of the page.

Comment: how can i contact them any link?

Comment: The below link might be of some help- https://www.facebook.com/help/?page=178608028874393